# python openstacksdk - userdata bash script not executing

Tags: python, bash, openstack

I want to execute a simple bash script which echos a text every 5 seconds. It works perfectly fine if i execute the userdata-script with the gui. if i try it with python Nothing happens and there are no log entrys in cloud-init-output.log either.

my code to encode my bash script with base 64 is:

`with open('mount.sh', 'r') as file:
    f = encodeutils.safe_encode(file.read().encode('utf-8'))
init_script = base64.b64encode(f).decode('utf-8')`

then i create the instance with create_server(..., userdata=init_script)

my mount.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
echo 'test'
sleep 5
done
```

anyone has an idea why it isn't working?

Comment: If you log into your instance and inspect the userdata by querying the metadata service, do you see the data you expect?

Comment: You can use the bash script directly itself from the GUI or from heat templates. Any reason going for python ?

Comment: i get the expected results if i start the instance over the gui. In python i get Ressource not found. It seems like my script will not be send to the instance at all.

Comment: @kvmahesh it is for a python app and the userdata feature is still missing.